# Authorization in Web.Config file not working after proper credentials

Tags: c#, asp.net, authorization

I want whenever a user if not logged in, and if he puts the page name directly in the url he should be directed to login page of the site.

I gaved authentication in my web.config file as below:-

```
 <authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" defaultUrl="~/" />
</authentication> 
<authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

But still when I login with my correct credentials, it still stays in the login page.

Also see my login button code:-

```
 protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String LoginID = txtUsername.Text.Trim().ToLower();
        String LoginPassword = txtPassword.Text.Trim();

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultCSRConnection"].ConnectionString);
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select username,password,usertype from tbl_User where username =@username and password=@password and Active= 1 ", conn);
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie("2", false);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", txtUsername.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", txtPassword.Text);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        if (dt != null && dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            if (dt.Rows[0]["usertype"].ToString() == "0") //SuperAdmin
            {
                Session["User"] = "0";
                Response.Redirect("csrpage.aspx");
            }
            else if (dt.Rows[0]["usertype"].ToString() == "1") // Admin
            {
                Session["User"] = "1";
                Response.Redirect("Admin.aspx");
            }
            else if (dt.Rows[0]["usertype"].ToString() == "2") // User
            {
                Session["User"] = "2";
                Response.Redirect("User.aspx");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "validation", "<script language='javascript'>alert('Invalid Username and Password')</script>");
        }

    }
```

Please help.

Comment: where are you telling IIS that these users are now known and not unknown?

Comment: @AndrewCounts: I didn't got you. What else I have to do to make IIS know that users are known and Unknown

Comment: Forms Authentication requires you to set a cookie so that the next request is checked against the cookie and can see that the user already put their login information in, else they just get redirected back again endlessly.

Comment: thanks for the clear info @AndrewCounts. Just let me know where to set this ? Please

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When you confirm username and password correct, you need call `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie("username", false);`

Comment: where to call this jeffrey ? is it on my login.aspx page and at which section, Page_Load or somewhere else?

Comment: @NadeemKhan You can add it at btnSubmit_Click method and before the Response.Rediect

Comment: what does the first parameter means 2= ?

Comment: it means I have to write 3 times as per my button click ?

Comment: @NadeemKhan the first parameter means username, you only need call this once

Comment: I tried with your answer , see the edited question code. but it is not working

Comment: you only added the code to the `SuperAdmin`, the rest of the roles would still not work.

Comment: @NadeemKhan I think you need put this before you judge the user type, and the first parameter is username(txtUsername.Text)

Comment: @JeffreyZhang: See the edited question, I changed like that.but still I can view the inner pages without login

Comment: @AndrewCounts: I added for all the roles now, still it is not working

Comment: in your current code, you added it before you even check the username and password.  At some point you'll just have to read the documentation at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.setauthcookie(v=vs.110).aspx and figure out how it's supposed to work.

Comment: @AndrewCounts: Sure, will look at the doc

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution from the below link:-

[Authentication issue](http://forums.asp.net/t/1375261.aspx?authorization%20to%20deny%20access%20pages%20under%20a%20folder%20not%20working) The main part for me in that was below added code:-

```
<location path="User">
   <system.web>
   <authorization>
   <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
       </system.web>
 </location>
```